# Why the title "Agunot" for S. Y. Agnon's short story?

Tags: short-stories, title, hebrew-language, s-y-agnon

[S. Y. Agnon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Yosef_Agnon)'s first influential story is "Agunot" - in fact, his chosen name "Agnon" comes from the same word.

The word "Agunot" is the plural form of the word "Agunah", which is the term for a woman whose husband has vanished or left without either dying or giving her a get (official divorce document), leaving her, essentially, stranded - she is still technically bound to her husband, unable to re-marry, but she either can't know if he's alive or has no way of obtaining a get.

What, then, does this have to do with the story "Agunot"? There is no case of an Agunah in the story itself.

**What is the importance of the title "Agunot"?**

Comment: I have not read the story, but is [this](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA#%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA) helpful to you? || "ב**עגונות** מובאים מצבי עגינות שונים, שכולם מכוונים למצב העגינות הבסיסי המוצג במבוא המדרשי לסיפור: העגינות שבין עם ישראל הגולה לבין השכינה. זוגות מנותקים נוספים, המדגימים מימושים שונים של הבסיס, הם: דינה ובן-אורי, בן-אורי והארון, ר' יחזקאל ופריידל."

Comment: @Shokhet - sounds like a reasonable interpretation; if you could translate that, write it up as an answer, and include support from the text it'd probably make a good answer ;)

Comment: I'd be much more confident doing that if I'd actually read the story. I don't know who any of those people are ¯\_(ツ)_/¯